# How to check if the EmaiID already exists or not in the dynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Iam using node js in the lambda function. When the user tries to put some data in the dynamo DB it should check whether the emailID exists in the db or not...Only when the emailID not exists data's should be updated in the DB...If the emailID exists it should prompt the user that emilID already exists...

**Below is my code which i used to put data into the db...But it won't check whether the emailID exists or not....I need to check whether the emilID exists or not in the db...Only if not exists data's should be updated**...Ho to do that pls help me

```
enter code here

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement

   var tableName = "Test";

    console.log(event.EmailID)

    var parms = {
        TableName : tableName,
       Item : {
            "EmailID" : event.EmailID,
            "CustomerName" : event.CustomerName,
            "PersonName" : event.PersonName,
            "EmailSent" : event.EmailSent,
             "Password" : event.Password
        }
    };
docClient.put(parms, function(err, data)
{
   if (err){
       callback(err)
   }
   else
   {
       callback(null,"Successfully updated data!!!")
   }
})
};
```

KeyconditionExpression:

```
        const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var doc

Client = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();


    var tableName = "Testing";

    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {



    var EmailID = event.EmailID; // or any other var which is having emaiID

       console.log(event)

    var params=  {
             TableName: 'Testing',

             Key: {ConditionExpression: 'attribute_exists(event.EmailID)'
                }
    };




    docClient.get(params, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            callback(err, data);
        }else{
            callback(err, data);
       }


    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a [conditional expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html). Scroll down to "Preventing Overwrites of an Existing Item" section header.

Comment: I added my code ....Am getting error  The provided key element does not match the schema...can u pls help me

Answer (score -3):

you can make emailId as a primary key of dynamodb as email id will be unique and it will not insert same item of same email again and it will update only when email is diffrent

so by making email id as a primary key will solve your problem.Hope it helps

Comment: From the docs "The PutItem operation will overwrite an item with the same key (if it exists). If you want to avoid this, use a condition expression."